# Is Bane from "The Dark Knight Rises" an Indian?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises

Is it just me, or are there others who think Bane's accent sounded like an Indian accent?

This seemed to be more pronounced in the plane scene at the beginning of the movie, when he says, "No one cared who I was, till I put on the mask".

Seriously, if I had closed my eyes during that scene, the first time I had seen the movie, I would have thought that Bane was actually from India. Also, the pit that is seen in the movie where Bane was during his younger days is [actually located in Rajasthan, India](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/13806/31332).

Comment: Just a random tidbit: in the Comics, Bane was born and raised in the prison _Pena Duro_ located in some post-revolutionary Latin American country. He's often depicted in DC video games with a strong Spanish Accent, as a result.

Comment: I can't say I picked up any Indian accent from Bane.

Answer (score 15):

**In-movie explanation:** [1](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Bane_(Tom_Hardy)#Early_life)

> Bane was reportedly born and raised in the **Pit, a hellish prison
>   located within a Middle Eastern country**. He came to regard the prison
>   as a home, a place where he learned "the truth about despair."

**From Bane himself:**

> "It's based on a guy named **Bartley Gorman**," he told us. (So, not Mr. Belevedere?) "He's the king of the gypsies, and he's a boxer, a bare-knuckle boxer, an **Irish** traveler, a gypsy." [2](http://www.vulture.com/2012/07/tom-hardy-explains-his-bane-voice-inspiration.html)
>
> According to Tom Hardy, he based his voice for Bane on **Bartley Gorman**
>   (1944 - 2002), an **Irish Traveller** who was the undefeated Bare-knuckle
>   boxing champion of the United Kingdom: "The choice of the accent is
>   actually a man called Bartley Gorman, who was a bare knuckle fighter,
>   a Romani gypsy. So I wanted to underpin the Latin, but a Romani Latin
>   opposed to Latino." [3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

**Out-of-movie-universe thoughts:**

The Mehrangarh fort is just a location they used for shooting the movie. If we still consider this to be *the Pit*, then we can assume Bane picked up the Indian dialect since he was born and raised in *the Pit* which results in his accent...

Comment: Since Roma people (a.k.a. gypsies) are basically a group of Indians who left the subcontinent in medieval times, it would make sense for the accent to be similar.

Comment: Related question; how did Bruce Wayne get to/from "a Middle Eastern country" so quickly?  The whole chronology of that segment seems completely out of whack.  Wouldn't he need months (or at least weeks) to recover from his injuries prior to his successful climb out of the pit?  Wouldn't Bane's plan in Gotham take far less time than that?

Comment: @aroth Bane's plan actually took around 5 months. See https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/how-long-did-it-take-bruce-to-recover

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't think that he is of Indian descent. The actual location for a scene does not conclusively reveal the actual location of the pit in the movie.

Ra's mentions that it (pit) was a hellish prison in a Middle Eastern country, but not the specific name. It could have been India, but it could very well have been Saudi Arabia, Iran, Iraq .. you get the point.

Also, his mask alters his speech so it is difficult to analyze where he might be from just by listening him.