# Why didn't the prisoners who helped Bruce try to escape from the pit themselves?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

Batman could escape the pit because he got proper moral guidance from the prisoners. They made him understand what it takes to leave the pit successfully. But it seemed they never wanted to leave the pit. Why is that? If they knew the principle to success very well, why did they not try? This is obvious from the movie, they were not well in that pit!

Comment: An important contributing factor was also the extensive training he received from *League of Shadows/Ra's al Ghul*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed the other prisoners (or some of them, the younger ones maybe) still try to escape from the pit, they just don't make it. There is a scene where one tries to escape while *Bruce* is still lying paralyzed.

Now the doctor could tell the others the *"secret"* of escaping (which I'm not sure he ever did). But in the end, just leaving away the rope is not enough, it is more of a mental stimulation. You still need the will and hope to escape and you still need the physical abilities (while *Bruce* was getting older and had his problems physically, he wasn't one of those hopeless failed existences imprisoned for years down there).

Even if the doctor had ever told the *"secret"* to the others, they probably were just too hopeless and desparate to try the climb without the rope and risk the rest they have of their lives. And even if they did, they either didn't bring the needed physical strength or, even more probably, the needed mental strength and the will and determination to escape and survive, having their will and hope broken after such a long time in the pit.

In the end I'm not sure the doctor was that aware of this *"secret"* of escape at all. It wasn't just about leaving away the rope, you still need a will as strong and determined as that of *Bruce*. And only when seeing such a character in *Bruce* the doctor realizes that there is finally someone after the kid who could make it out of the pit and he gives him the final stimulation he needs.

Comment: Indeed a compact answer!

Answer (score 4):

Those who had the *heart* and *really willed* to escape did try, but sans success. This is clearly shown in the scene where Bruce is bed ridden with a broken back and a man tries to escape but eventually falls, banging into the wall several times and then going limp.

Moreover, Bruce was guided and supported by two very old and frail men, none of whom could have themselves taken the leap.

Comment: I judge my `title` of the question has been misleading. going to edit it!

Comment: But I think the answer still answers what you are asking.....

Answer (score 2):

I would say that all of the prisoners had lost hope about escaping. Apart from Bruce, we never see anyone trying to climb out of the pit during his stay in prison.

However, I am sure that Bruce's escape inspires prisoners who will take the challenge of climbing it after.

This would be in resonance with one of the roles of Batman in Gotham City, which is to give hope to the "small people" living here.
Indeed, we see children smiling when they understand he is back, also the feats of Batman seem to inspire the character of John Blake into becoming a vigilante hero.
Bruce Wayne / Batman is an inspiration for everybody !

Comment: Why did not the prisoner who mentally strengthened him (other than the doctor) take the leap? It seemed he knew how to get success. Then why did not he try? It was implied `Mental strength is more important than physical strength` in the movie and there is no reason to think `Bruce's physical strength was greater than anybody`.

Comment: As a side note, the other prisoners indeed try to climb out, they just don't have success. There is a scene where one tries, while *Bruce* is still lying paralyzed. And also the other prisoners don't need to climb out following his guidance, since *Bruce* once out throws down a rope, to make an end to this terribly hopeless prison.

Comment: @Mistu4u I agree with your opinion, mental strength is more important to escape. Bruce had a stronger will to escape because he had his motivation, stuff waiting for him outside (the need to save Gotham and its people). The doctor saw in Bruce someone who could achieve to escape. He himself knew he didn't have the mental strength to do it (not enough motivation, maybe nobody outside waiting for him, and maybe life in the prison was not so unpleasant to him).

Comment: @Christian Rau Thank you for adding this information, I did not remember everything from those scenes.